# Keyboard settings changing partially/not at all in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, mate

I can't change my keyboard layout in Mate settings. Not sure what's wrong here.

I did run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, but it did not fix the problem.

So, I set layouts to this, Dvorak + Russian:
[image]

Then I try using the system, and every time a window opens, the layout switches to qwerty. I go to settings and see everything is correct. But when I try switching the layout, I see it cycle through the old sequence.

I right-click the menu and see the old setting:
[image]

So I ran `dpkg-reconfigure`, rebooted, and now the setting file is this:

```
 $ cat /etc/default/keyboard
 # KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

 # Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

 XKBMODEL="pc105"
 XKBLAYOUT="us"
 XKBVARIANT="dvorak-alt-intl"
```

Which is correct, but for some reason, MATE panel thinks layouts are old, and it switches it to qwerty US English every time I switch to another input box or a window. (Switch key is "caps lock", so it's not my fault either that it switches every time.)

How can I reset the settings to the old one? How can I purge the user settings for keyboard?

**edit:** tried removing and re-adding the English layout. It partially did work, now English layout is only one, and it does not switch on its own.

The strange thing is that I can't switch layout until I have an active cursor in a text box. In a browser I can't swich layout when no input box is focused.

Comment: In the 1st screenshot it seems the first line actually contains 2 layouts. So it's not Dvorak+Ru, but US+Dvorak+Ru. Try removing all the En layouts so that you end up with a Ru only. Then try adding the one En you prefer.

Comment: It partially did work. I actually tried it before, but somehow now it fixed the 2 and independent English layouts problem. But now I can't switch layouts not having a focused text box, this is weird.

Comment: Try changing the switch key.

Comment: :( did not work and it actually got the 2 english layouts problem back.

Comment: I tried re-adding the layout, it did fix it again, but switching was still broken. So I changed the switch key again, and now the layouts got broken again the same old way (en-ru-en_dvorak_alt_intl)

Comment: I suspect file permissions might be wrongw and the keyboard manager can't write to settings file, but it keeps them the way I want while it's still opened. As long as I change something, MATE, as I suspect, syncs it with the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to @pomsky for pushing me to change settings and see the pattern.

The reason was the fcitx utility which lived its own life and was overriding MATE keyboard widget.

[image]

Solution:

```
$ sudo apt remove fcitx
$ killall fcitx -9
$ killall fcitx-qimpanel -9
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the solution to remove `fcitx` did not work for me because it wasn't actually installed. Instead, it appeared that the keyboard preferences in Control Center got overwritten by iBus preferences (also in Control Center).

Creating two layouts in iBus preferences along with the keyboard preferences helped to solve the problem.